# Book about a giant spaceship that passes through the solar system

Tags: story-identification, books, space-opera

The book is ~20 years old. Its plot is a gigantic spaceship (builders unknown) that passes through our solar system and a delegation from Earth is sent and discovers multiple species of aliens. There was a follow up book that explored a space in the center of the ship that was hell like.

Comment: The one that pops immediately to mind is [*Rendezvous with Rama*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_with_Rama); have you eliminated any possibilities?

Comment: Or [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_(novel)] (Eon) by Greg Bear. Technically not really a spaceship but a stable asteroïd. But delegations from Earth are sent and discovers multiple species of aliens.

Comment: What a nice question! Uncovers basically an entire sub-genre.

Comment: @DavidW The book in question is described as about 20 years old, so that eliminates *Rama*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is [Marrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(novel)), the first of the *Great Ship* novels by Robert Reed.

> When a jovian-sized, artificially-created structure enters the galaxy,
> a society of technologically advanced humans (capable of interstellar
> flight and functionally immortal) are the first to intercept and
> investigate it. Finding it to be an intergalactic ship, they decide to
> convert it into a cruise ship, inviting alien races to join them in
> its massive, uncharted interior as it makes a slow circumnavigation of
> the Milky Way.
>
> [image]

A key plot point is that a group of explorer get stuck on a planet lurking at the centre of this ship. It has energetic volcanism and is really quite an unpleasant environment.

> After thousands of years, with over 200 billion creatures living in
> its upper levels, a group of explorers discover a planet hidden in the
> core of the Great Ship. As they explore it, however, an ionic blast
> cuts them off from the rest of the ship and destroys much of their
> technology. Because this planet, Marrow, is slowly expanding, the
> explorers reason that a new bridge can be built in another 5,000
> years. They thus begin a civilization on the surface of Marrow.

Answer (score 25):

This could be the [Rendezvous with Rama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_with_Rama) series, depending on what you mean by hell at the centre.

- The spaceship(s) have picked up multiple species as they pass through various systems
- The destination is a kind of heaven, and has some religious connotations. Not all of the alien individuals or species qualify for ascension
- The experiences of the alien races on the ship can be seen as a metaphor for hell

Comment: "a delegation...discovers multiple species of aliens." The humans who entered Rama discovered what they called "biots" (portmantau of "biological robots.") The biots resembled biological organisms, but none of them, as I recall, seemed to be any more intelligent than an insect. They issued from seeming automated factories as Rama approached the Sun, they performed various, obscure tasks, and then they all disappeared (back to their factories? into the central sea? I forget) when Rama was moving back toward interstellar space. They basically ignored the humans when the humans tried to interact.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there were no real aliens in the first book. Rama II had the Avians, "octospiders" and "myrmicats". Iirc the eagle headed folk (builders of the spaceships) didn't show up until the 3rd book in the series

Comment: Hunh! I didn't know about the sequels. I'll have to add those to my reading list.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Don't bother reading them - sequels in name only and written by someone else with minor input from Clarke. Vastly inferior.

Comment: I'll double down on @OmnivoreNZ's comment - the sequels are ... not great ... I did read them all, mind you, #OCD.

Comment: I'll triple down on @OmnivoreNZ's comment. Maybe the first sequel is worth reading. Up to the weird sex stuff, at least, but that's mostly at the end if I remember right, or maybe even the beginning of the third book. It gets _really_ weird and uncomfortable in later books.

Comment: @Thierry TBH I wouldn't rate the original, except for completists who want to cover Golden Age SF. My short summary of RwR would be "exploring an alien space ship, but made *really* boring". ;) Clarke was a great conceptual thinker, but I'm not convinced about his ability to write characters or plot around those concepts. (Although he was still better than the hack he worked with on the sequels.)

Comment: @Graham Kind of agree with you. But when reading the first book, I was just amazed by the descriptions: not too much but not too little, it was just perfectly perfect, which made it my top 1 book.

Comment: @Itération122442 I was more amazed by the fact I finished it and I found I literally didn't care.  Not about any character, not about Rama, not about who made it, not about knowing anything more about it.  As a keen reader, that's really quite something for me.  I get that occasionally when I speed-read crappy superficial romance books for something to do on holiday, but I wasn't expecting that from someone as famous as Clarke.  Re-reading, his descriptions of Rama are pretty good, I agree.  It's everything else which makes it a story (or not!) which is amateur-hour trash.

Comment: @Graham My disappointment with RwR was the 50 digit code on the bomb that was split into five 10 digit codes that could be brute force cracked one at a time in a fairly insignificant amount of time.  For whatever reason, *that* was the part of the story that just caused immense disappointment for me.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson I'd forgotten that detail. TBH I think that's a sign generally of how bad the book is. When you have such a wide choice of trashy elements, it's safe to say the best place to file it is the trash.

Comment: @Graham The Sierra game was a pretty good adventure for its time, though :P Clarke was never very good with characters; it's really more reading for the technically minded (like me :D ). The characters are just there to provide a vaguely human view on the alien... and to make it a more "classical" novel, rather than a fictional documentary :D Of course, as is usually the case with even the more realistic sci-fi novels of the time, the computer stuff is way off the mark, though to be fair, improperly implemented security like that is way too common even today :)

Comment: @SolomonSlow don't pay any attention to those classical ***"nattering nabobs of negativity".*** The sequels are tóó, worth your time, they're just pretty long, and the main protagonist is a female of color. I suppose thát bothers a  lot of readers, either on a conscious, or on a *sub*conscious level....

Comment: @GwenKillerby Your comment would be a lot better if you removed the insinuations about the bias other commenters may have from it. Unless there have been comments removed (Always a possibility) There is NOTHING in what has been said by anybody which even remotely points towards your conclusion as to why people don't like the sequels.

Answer (score 7):

As I remember, another book with a similar plot of a giant spaceship entering the solar system and astronauts visiting it was James White's *All Judgement Fled* 1966.

> Science fiction writer Mike Resnick called the novel "Rendezvous with Rama done right."

https://www.reddit.com/r/printSF/comments/6t52gp/all_judgment_fled_by_james_white/

Answer (score 3):

**Possibly Colin Greenland's *[Take Back Plenty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_Back_Plenty)* (1990)**

The giant spaceship is called Plenty. If I recall correctly, it isn't inhabited when the delegation from Earth gets there, but it soon becomes populated by an assortment of alien species from the (non-realistic) Solar System and sets off for distant stars. The sequel, *Seasons of Plenty*, explores the strange interior of Plenty, which has some horrible elements. In the third and last book, *Mother of Plenty*, Plenty arrives at a star inhabited by hostile aliens, and the protagonist must fight to save herself and her friends.

[image]

Comment: Looks like what the cover is emphasizing _has nothing much to do_ with the actual book, in classic Sci-Fi tradition!

Comment: Isn't that a Commodore 64 ?

Comment: @davidbak It is probably of vital importance to show in unambiguous fashion that you are a mammalian species! (And, as a minor detail, that you typically don't have more than two infants at once which indicates intense brood care.)